# regex find type of string

Tags: regex

i try write a regex rule for find mathes like

```
From: "Turkcell Online" <sungwon7306@hanmail.net>
```

Turkcell is a big telecom. company in turkey and it domain name turkcell.com.tr.

if the string begin with From : "Turkcell.* but doesn't contain turkcell.com.tr i want to catch this string

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Begin by `From: "Turkcell`:

```
^From:\s"Turkcell
```

Doesn't contain `turkcell.com.tr` (this is called a negative lookahead):

```
(?!.*turkcell\.com\.tr)
```

And both combined give you the needed regex:

```
(?!.*turkcell\.com\.tr)^From:\s"Turkcell.*
```